# Integral tends to infty

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How can we prove that $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\searrow 0} \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon} \displaystyle\int_0^1 \left [\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\arctan^2\left (\dfrac{x}{\varepsilon}\right )\right ]^2 dx=+\infty$?

I came across this integral in studying the Heaviside aproximation function. I used the following sharp estimate:

$\arctan(x)<\dfrac{\pi^2 x}{4+\sqrt{32+(2\pi x)^2}}, \forall\ x>0$, but the limit goes to $0$ (I computed it exactly with wolfram). This estimation and many others can be found here:

https://journalofinequalitiesandapplications.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13660-018-1734-7

The integral in the statement is simulated here:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+1000000000+%281%2F4+-+%281%2Fpi%5E2%29+%28arctan%2810000000000+x%29%29%29%5E2+dx

But I wonder if it can be proved that it really tends to infinity. Maybe there are some singularities and the program gives some big errors.

Comment: Do you mean $\arctan^2\bigl((x/\varepsilon)^2\bigr)$ in the integrand?

Comment: If you do the substitution $t = x/\varepsilon$, you get the integral of a positive function on $[0, +\infty)$. The result cannot be $0$.

Comment: Indeed the limit should converge to $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{\pi^2} \arctan^2 \bigl( t^2 \bigr) \right]^2 \, \mathrm{d}t \approx 0.0748664. $$

Comment: I modified the statement. I was my mistake. Please sorry about that...

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%281%2F4+-+ArcTan%5Bt%5D%5E2%2FPi%5E2%29%5E2%2C%7Bt%2C0%2CInfinity%7D%5D

Comment: So it does not show a correct value on my simulation. Interesting. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

OHH, please sorry. I made a mistake putting an extra $2$. It should be:

$$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\searrow 0} \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon} \displaystyle\int_0^1 \left [\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\arctan^2\left (\dfrac{x}{\varepsilon}\right )\right ]^2 dx=+\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

We can approach the value given by @Sangchul Lee in comments.

Let
$$f(t)= \left[\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{\pi^2} \arctan^2 \bigl( t^2 \bigr) \right]^2 $$ and write for example
$$\int_0^\infty f(t)\,dt=\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt+\int_1^\infty f(t)\,dt$$ For the first integral, using
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{16}-\frac{t^4}{2 \pi ^2}+\frac{\left(3+\pi ^2\right) t^8}{3 \pi
   ^4}-\frac{\left(120+23 \pi ^2\right) t^{12}}{90 \pi ^4}+\frac{22 \left(7+\pi
   ^2\right) t^{16}}{105 \pi ^4}-\frac{\left(14360+1689 \pi ^2\right) t^{20}}{9450
   \pi ^4}+\frac{\left(239327+24405 \pi ^2\right) t^{24}}{155925 \pi
   ^4}+O\left(t^{28}\right)$$
$$\color{blue}{\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt \sim \frac{1}{16}-\frac{58331177}{804053250 \pi ^2}+\frac{15323818}{182739375 \pi ^4}}$$
For the second integral, using
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{\pi ^2 t^4}-\frac{2}{\pi ^3 t^6}+\frac{3-2 \pi ^2}{3 \pi ^4 t^8}+\frac{2}{\pi ^3 t^{10}}+\frac{23 \pi ^2-60}{45 \pi ^4
   t^{12}}-\frac{28}{15 \pi ^3 t^{14}}-\frac{22 \left(2 \pi ^2-7\right)}{105 \pi ^4
   t^{16}}+\frac{1636}{945 \pi ^3 t^{18}}+\frac{1689 \pi ^2-7180}{4725 \pi ^4
   t^{20}}-\frac{282}{175 \pi ^3 t^{22}}+\frac{239327-48810 \pi ^2}{155925 \pi ^4
   t^{24}}+\frac{26126}{17325 \pi ^3
   t^{26}}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^{28}}\right)$$
$$\color{blue}{\int_1^\infty f(t)\,dt \sim \frac{5946893}{22713075 \pi ^2}-\frac{474283184}{2010133125 \pi
   ^3}+\frac{1446994}{13627845 \pi ^4}}$$

So
$$\color{red}{\int_0^\infty f(t)\,dt \sim \frac{1}{16}+\frac{22169236787}{117123756750 \pi ^2}-\frac{474283184}{2010133125 \pi ^3}+\frac{500797244128}{2635284526875 \pi ^4}}$$ which is $0.0760194$.

**Edit**

After the edit of the question, the problem is much simpler with
$$f(t)= \left[\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{\pi^2} \arctan^2 \bigl( t \bigr) \right]^2 $$ since there is an antiderivative.

Expanding the square,we face two integrals
$$I_1=\int\arctan^2(t)\,dt \qquad \text{and} \qquad I_2=\int\arctan^4(t)\,dt$$ Making $t=\tan(u)$
$$I_1=\int u^2 \sec ^2(u)\,du \qquad \text{and} \qquad I_2=\int u^4 \sec ^2(u)\,du $$ which can express in terms of the polylogarithm function.

Recombining the antiderivatives and using the bounds
$$\int_0^\infty \left[\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{\pi^2} \arctan^2 \bigl( t \bigr) \right]^2 =\frac{3 }{\pi ^3}\zeta (3)$$

Using, as before, series expansions
$$\color{blue}{\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt \sim \frac{1}{16}+\frac{40832183318753}{559056788915625 \pi
   ^4}-\frac{56140585778267}{452214824811750 \pi ^2}}$$
$$\color{blue}{\int_1^\infty f(t)\,dt \sim \frac{1112361876473779}{7102091799928125 \pi
   ^4}-\frac{478852611552730453}{679000559454842625 \pi
   ^3}+\frac{2370558288062177347}{2799586611272075625 \pi ^2}}$$

This gives $\sim 0.11533$ while $\frac{3 }{\pi ^3}\zeta (3)\sim 0.11630$.

Comment: In what program do you simulate this integral?